# Can modern PC's boot installation disc from internal SATA Blu Ray/DVD drive through sata-to-usb enclosure?

Tags: boot, bootable-media, blu-ray, enclosures, sata-to-usb

Does booting operating system installation discs from Blu ray sata drive through SATA-to-USB enclosure work?

Answer (score 0):

Like a Blu-Ray optical drive? Yes. It should be able to read the optical drive through the SATA connection. Check your BIOS boot settings.